# synchronize two mysql databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there  a way of synchronizing two databases as a batch process?

I have a database on my server but i want to have the same database
running on localhost , i know i can download the entirely database and import it
to localhost but

is there a way to import it once and then just run the insert,update,delete querys 
that have been done on the server? 
is there a log where queries that have been runned are stored? (queries not resultsets)

So far the only way i found it possible was to keep data structure and import all the data every day

Thanks !

Comment: not sure, but maybe replication?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is software to actually do this (version control and push/replicate databases). Off the top of my head, something available for sql server and mysql is called Redgate (http://www.red-gate.com/). Alternatively docker might offer a similar service but for mysql (https://docker.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can run a cron to do so ... Meaning write a script for exporting database from server and import the same using mysqldump command so in that way you would be able to synchronized the same..

Answer (score 0):

to see the log of my sql queries.. please follow this
Edit mysql configuration file:

- vi /etc/my.cnf

This will only log slow queries. You need the general log if you want to see all queries.

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = "/opt/lampp/logs/query.log"
```

Note that you'll need to restart the server for this to take effect. Also, you should only use this type of logging during testing as it does cause slowdown.

for more in detail [how-to-enable-general-query-log-in-mysql-under-linux](http://www.jovicailic.org/2012/07/how-to-enable-general-query-log-in-mysql-under-linux/)